# Get menu item title from its ID

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get the title of my top-level navigation. I already know the ID of the top-level menu-item but i need to get its title. How can one do that?

I currently have menu like this:

- Level1

  - Level2 #1
  - Level2 #2
  - Level2 #3

If im on any of the level 2 pages i have the Level 1 **menu-item** ID. I need to get the title in the current theme-location instance.

```
   <?php if(getTopSelectedMenu('primary')):
            $topParent = intval(getTopSelectedMenu('primary'));
            $topParentTitle = "";
    ?>
        <div class="sidebar-menu-headline"><?=$topParentTitle?><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
    <?php

        $args = array(
            'menu' => '',
            'menu_class' => 'sidebar-menu',
            'container' => 'ul',
            'theme_location' => 'primary',
            'level' => 2,
            'child_of' => $topParent,
            'echo' => FALSE,
            'fallback_cb' => '__return_false'
        );
        $submenu = wp_nav_menu( $args );

        if ( ! empty ($submenu) )echo $submenu;

    ?>
```

Comment: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/16337/121266

Comment: @AlivetoDie from id?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use the below function to get menu title by passing menu id.

```
Function: wp_get_nav_menu_object($menu) // $menu can be 'id','name' or 'slug'
Returns : Object (
       term_id => 4
       name => My Menu Name
       slug => my-menu-name
       term_group => 0
       term_taxonomy_id => 4
       taxonomy => nav_menu
       description => 
       parent => 0
       count => 6
   )

// in your case.
$menu = wp_get_nav_menu_object($topParent );
$menu_title = $menu->name;
```

You can find more information here. https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_nav_menu_object

To get the Menu title, Use the below code

```
if(getTopSelectedMenu('primary')){
    $topParentId = intval(getTopSelectedMenu('primary'));
    $menuLocations = get_nav_menu_locations(); // Get our nav locations (set in our theme, usually functions.php)
                                           // This returns an array of menu locations ([LOCATION_NAME] = MENU_ID);

    $menu =  wp_get_nav_menu_object($menuLocations['primary']) ; // Get the *primary* menu object

    $primaryNav = wp_get_nav_menu_items($menu->term_id); // Get the array of wp objects, the nav items for our queried location.

    foreach ( $primaryNav as $navItem ) {
        if ($navItem->ID == $topParentId ) {
            $topParentTitle = $navItem->title;
        }
    }
}
<div class="sidebar-menu-headline"><?=$topParentTitle?><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i></div>
```

Comment: Okay, let me clarify. I need the menu-item title, not the menu name. For example if i have > Level 1 Menu(id: 1), >> Level 2 Menu(id: 2) , >> Level 2 Menu2(id:3) I currently have the top-level menu id (1 in this example). I need to get the title (Level 1 Menu) from this navigation instance

Comment: Edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks. Worked like a charm, just approve my little hotfix. Also, I love that u explained what does what :)

Answer (score -1):

Right, you want simple! I got you.

If you know the URL, use `url_to_postid()`:

```php
$actual_id = url_to_postid($url);
$the_title = get_the_title($actual_id);
```

or simply:

```php
$the_title = get_the_title(url_to_postid($url));
```

Haven't really come across a time where this was inaccurate!

Comment: Well, except for this time.

He wants the navigation label, not the post title.